# Need service manual for Mahindra Scorpio CRDe 2006 model

Tags: electrical, wiring, electronics, service-manual

I am trying to diagnose a problem with the ECU of my Mahindra Scorpio, I am looking for Fuses and Relays where it's being located, Specifically looking for schematics and wiring diagram of my car..

Please anybody can provide this

Thank you

Comment: simple search gives : http://solopdf.com/mahindra_scorpio.htm

Comment: Please list what you have done to try and find the diagrams so we don't waste our time in the same avenues.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question due to low-quality.